# C# EPPlus move "generated sum field" into columnfields

Tags: c#, excel, pivot, pivot-table, epplus

I need to use epplus instead of interop and in my excel file there is one "field" in the pivot table I can not get a hold of...

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZDIc.jpg)

This "Values" field is automatically generated from my code and does not show up in any of the fields I am able to access so far. Not sure if it is a field anyway.

```
var filesField = pivotTable.Fields["Files"];
filesField.Name = "Files";
pivotTable.DataFields.Add(filesField);
var sizeField = pivotTable.Fields["Size"];
sizeField.Name = "Size";
pivotTable.DataFields.Add(sizeField);
```

This creates the fields I need for my pivot table/chart and from those this "Values" field in the picture is created.

With interop I did this:

```
Pivotfield datafield = pivotTable.PivotFields("Daten");
```

But this does not work with eeplus, since the field "Daten" is not there.

I am trying to something like this, but it also could be that here i need to access the chart by itself?

```
var datafield = // some code to catch this sum
pivotTable.ColumnFields.Add(datafield);
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer to my question. Since this "Values" field is auto generated and i could not access it I tried something else.

Turns out this line:

```
pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
```

did the trick.
Did not research it yet, but I thought I share the answer to my problem.